# return the address of a extern variables in header file

Tags: c, global-variables, extern

## x.h

```
typedef struct _x_t {
 int64_t id;
} x_t;

extern x_t x;

static inline x_t* get_x() {
   return &x;
}
```

## x.c

```
#include "x.h"
x_t x;
```

## app.c

```
get_x()->id = 5;
```

The reason why I ask this is I am sure the `get_x()->id = 5` was executed and when I access the `get_x()->id`, it become to a random value on some case.

So I want to know if the code in the x.h is always right? if not,  when it will have issue?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. `get_x` will return the address of the same, unique, global variable every time. You should post the code that caused it to be "random value on some case".

Comment: Why writing function `get_x()`? Why are not accessing `x` directly (like, `x.id`)? `x` is a global variable, make sure that its not getting modified by other part of your program. Post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am really upset about the rules stackoverflow has defined for "close" since all the 2 topics I send recently (with careful description) got "close" votes.   if people can't ask the question when their code doesn't work, when they don't know what tool to use on some case,  what we can do with stackoverflow?

Comment: thank @ybungalobill,  I am still debug with this issue and I didn't find out what is the code put it to a random value.  the code in x.h was write by another people, and it just looks strange to me.   I will give an update once I figure out the root cause.

Comment: @zhihuifan: I cast that close vote, for the reasons I said in my comment above. This question right now is more of a code-review, and cannot have much of an answer besides a simple "Yes". You can fix your question and I will retract my vote. The question should contain the code that doesn't work, not the code that works.

Comment: Hi @ybungalobill:  if it is you cast the "close" vote,  then it is ok to me since you at least read and reply.   I will be unhappy if people just cast the "close" vote easily without any comments.